# Fair dice expected outcome

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I was wondering if I answered the question below correctly.

You have two fair 6-sided dice.

a)Calculate $E[N]$ of a single die, expected outcome.

b)Consider the random variable $M =N_1 +N_2$, the sum of the faces of the two dice.  State the PMF of $M,P_{M}[m]$.

A) $E[N] = NP[N]$

PMF of single die: $P_{N}[n] = 1/6, n\in${$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$}

$E[N] = (1/6)N$

B)  $P_{M}[m] = 1/36, m\in${$2,3, ..., 12$}

Comment: For A, for E[N] you should be able to calculate an exact number (since you know the probability and value for each outcome). For B, the probability of the sums aren't all equal to 1/36, ex: 2 is less likely to occur than 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, $N$ is a discrete random variable that maps an outcome of a single roll of the fair dice to $\{1,2,3,5,6\}$.

This is obvious, because a normal 6-sided fair dice has $6$ sides each numbered from $1$ to $6$ and each roll of the dice gives you an unique outcome.

The expected value of $N$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{6} n\cdot P(N=n)$.

Since the dice is fair, the probability of landing on any one of the sides is equal.

Thus, $\forall n\in\{1,2,3,5,6\} , P(N=n) = \frac{1}{6}$.

Substituting into the formula of $E[N]$, you will obtain $E[N]= \sum_{n=1}^{6} n\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{2}.$

Let $M$ denote the sum of the faces of $2$ dice rolls.

You made a mistake in thinking that $M$ is uniformly distributed.

Supposed the sum of the faces of $2$ dice rolls is $2$, then the only outcome would be to obtain $1$ on both dice rolls.

However, it is not always the case that there is only $1$ outcome.

Let $M=4$. There are $3$ (and not $1$ as you assumed) possible outcomes that have the sum as $4$.

1st dice - $2$, 2nd dice - $2$

1st dice - $1$, 2nd dice - $3$

1st dice - $3$, 2nd dice - $1$

Since rolls of dice are independent, the random variables $N_1$ and $N_2$ (as described in your post) are independent.

Note that $P(N_1 = k$ and $N_2 = l) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$ for all $k,l = 1,2,3,5,6$.

So, as mentioned in the case of $M=4$, $P(M=4) = \frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Note that $M\in \{2,3,...,11,12\}$, you should attempt to derive the PMF of $M$ for other values besides $4$.

At the end, verify that $\sum_{m=2}^{12} P(M=m) = 1$, which satisfies the axiom of probability that $P(\Omega) = 1$ , where $\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes.

Comment: If I were to get the expected outcome of M would the following be correct? $E[M]= \sum\limits_{m=1}^{36} m * \frac{1}{36} = \frac{7}{12} $

Comment: There is some error in your syntax for LaTeX. I can't read what you are implying. But $E[M] = \sum_{m=2}^{12} m\cdot P(M=m)$.

Comment: Note that $M\in \{2,3,...,11,12\}$. Your formula for Expectation is wrong, and it is redundant to sum values of $M$ that is larger than $12$. For example, $P(M=13) = 0$ since there is no possible way you can obtain a sum of $13$ from $2$ rolls of dice.

Comment: So if I did the summation correctly, $E[M] = \frac{11(12)}{2} * \frac{1}{36} = \frac{11}{6}$